# How to check a \n character in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am having an address like

```
"1500 bustleton pike churchville,
Southampton, PA 18966, United States"
```

and its also present in my database. But when i used in query like

```
select id from companies where CompanyAddress 
LIKE '1500 bustleton pike churchville,
Southampton, PA 18966, United States'
```

it not returning any value. Because its contain a new line after `"churchville,"`. Please help me to solve this

Comment: Since you are not using any wild character like % in LIKE clause, why don't you use where clause?

Comment: i also checked with select id from companies where CompanyAddress 
= '1500 bustleton pike churchville,
Southampton, PA 18966, United States'  still its not working

Comment: @Praseetha , This is off topic , but i suggest to save address in different parts , Like - street , city, country . That is better approach

Answer (score 0):

There are two potential problems:

1. Most likely issue is that it's a \n (LF) and/or \r\n  (CRLF) check.
2. Second is that there are or are not spaces around the line break

If you're really not sure, check out the REPLACE() function: find out if your search is \n or \r\n and then match in the following:

```
select id from companies
    WHERE REPLACE(CompanyAddress, '\n', '\r\n') =
'1500 bustleton pike churchville,
Southampton, PA 18966, United States'
```

where the second parameter in the `REPLACE` is the one you have in source code. Check the spaces in query match (or also remove spaces with `REPLACE`).

I would suggest ensuring the string is entered in a standard form for future searching to get around this problem.

NOTE: don't do this on a large file as the search won't be indexed.

Answer (score 0):

> THERE ARE MANY WAYS TO DO IT..!!

Use MYSQL **`TRIM()`**:

```
select id from companies where trim(BOTH '\n' from CompanyAddress)
LIKE '%1500 bustleton pike churchville, Southampton, PA 18966, United States%'
```

If you works with **MySql 5.1**, use **`REPLACE()`**:

```
select id from companies where REPLACE(CompanyAddress,'\r\n',' ')
LIKE '%1500 bustleton pike churchville, Southampton, PA 18966, United States%'
```